# How to use Azure.Data.Tables TableClient with dependency injection multiple tables?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/create-table-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cvisual-studio#5---configure-the-table-client-in-startupcs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
    
    var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CosmosTableApi");
    services.AddSingleton<TableClient>(new TableClient(connectionString, "WeatherData"));
    
    services.AddSingleton<TablesService>();
}
```

I understand how this is working but lets introduce a second table **OceanData**. How would that work?

```
services.AddSingleton<TableClient>(new TableClient(connectionString, "OceanData"));        
services.AddSingleton<OceanDataService>();
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, TablesService tablesService, OceanDataService oceanDataService)
```

The problem is when I call **oceanDataService.GetAllRows** it tries to query the WeatherData table instead!

```
public OcenDataService(TableClient tableClient)
        {
            _tableClient = tableClient;
        }
```

It looks like I should instead be doing something like

```
services.AddSingleton(new TableServiceClient(connectionString));
```

But I don't think that is right as I only get to access table names in the service class and not the table data...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is happening because your first `TableClient` in your DI container will be resolved which points to `WeatherData` table. You can very well go with `TableServiceClient` approach you mentioned in your post and create `TableClient` instance wherever you need it using the service client and specific table name.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject multiple tables as below.

Startup.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITableStorageService<{TableName}>>(provider =>
new TableStorageService<{TableName}>(provider.GetRequiredService<TableServiceClient>(), nameof({TableName})));
```

TableStorageService.cs:

```
public class TableStorageService<T> : 
          ITableStorageService<T> where T : class, ITableEntity, new()

    {
        private readonly TableClient _tableClient;

        public TableStorageService(TableServiceClient tableServiceClient, string tableName)
            => _tableClient = tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);

        public ValueTask<List<T>> QueryAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query)
            => _tableClient.QueryAsync(query).ToListAsync();

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAllRows()
        {
            return _tableClient.Query<T>();
        }
    }
```